# How do I redirect to a specific page after inserting data in cakePHP scaffolding?

Tags: php, cakephp

Well I am using Scaffolding concept in cakePHP for the first time, everything runs quite okay, but the problem I am facing is: after the data getting inserted into the database the page is automatically redirected to a success page.

I just want it to redirect my custom action page.

Can I do it in cakePHP Scaffoliding?

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

No! We can not add our custom redirection in scaffolding. Scaffolding is more like non-production deployment which is mostly used to give the initial idea about the framework and its feasibility towards your application.

To be precise to your question, you have to skip Scaffolding for that particular action,  write saving logic and then redirect it to wherever you want. 
You can bake the controller and create actions which will save your time and you can add your redirection in that.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

After surfing a lot I found the idea, Here is how you can redirect to your custom action in cakePHP Scaffolding.

```
public function afterScaffoldSave() {
         $this->redirect($this->referer());
      }

afterScaffoldSave() does the trick!
hope this helps to others who has the same problem!
```